# How to set column names in R by repeating character?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I want to create a column name in R called L1, L2, ..., up to L200. How could I do this for a data frame?

I tried `colnames(df) <- c('L1':'L200')`, but this does not work (returns error message `NAs introduced by coercion`), even though there are 200 columns.

Help on this appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
colnames(df) <- paste0("L", 1:200)
```

or to make it more automatic

```
colnames(df) <- paste0("L", seq_along(df))
```

NOTE: The range (`:`) operator works for integer, and not with `character` in `base R`  i.e. 'L1' is a string, while `1` is integer, so `1:200` gives the range of values from 1 to 200

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
colnames(df) <- sprintf("L%d", 1:200)
```